# Is there a browser or addon that can capture data with a regular expression (regex) whilst browsing?

Tags: browser-addons, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions

I would like to be able browse the web and have my browser (plus addon) automatically record any text that matches a given pattern (e.g. regular expression) along, optionally, with the URL it appeared on and a timestamp.

This would function like an automatic journal of pattern-matched strings during a day of browsing.

Examples of classes of pattern:

- URLs
- Names

(I realise that there are a number of browser addons to search in-page and on command using regular expressions, and separately there are crawling and browser automation addons, but nothing to do automatic journalling.)

Thanks for any thoughts!